# USB 3.0 hard drive dock only in USB 2

Tags: 16.04, usb

On my ubuntu 16.04, I have an usb3 disk dock, enermax EB311SC, but it is only recognized as an usb2.1 bay. It has external power, so I guess usb3 power requirement shouldn't matter. So speed is limited to somehow 50Mo/s, even in the disk performace utility of ubuntu. Usb3 is working on my computer, a external drive, plugged on the same port is working in usb3.0, at the right speed.

Here are some command line output. If anyone needs more, just ask!

`~$ lsusb -t`:

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 12, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 3, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 12M
```

`~$ lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/003/012 | grep bcdUSB`:

```
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
  bcdUSB               2.10
```

`~$ dmseg`

```
[ 1908.593789] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 1908.795561] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2561
[ 1908.795569] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[ 1908.795574] usb 3-1: Product: USB to SATA bridge
[ 1908.795578] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: OImaster
[ 1908.795581] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 201501300013
[ 1908.797458] scsi host7: uas
[ 1908.801585] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JMicron                   9122 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 1908.803521] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[ 1908.803810] sd 7:0:0:0: [sda] 15628053168 512-byte logical blocks: (8.00 TB/7.28 TiB)
[ 1908.805338] sd 7:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[ 1908.805344] sd 7:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 67 00 10 08
[ 1908.805998] sd 7:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[ 1908.869565]  sda: sda1
[ 1908.873381] sd 7:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[ 1910.032271] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

Kernel update didn't help (`Linux 4.15.0-42-generic`)

Any help ?